# append textarea innerhtml to an array and then search ids in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Im making a function that will get innerHTML of textarea in an array and then it will search ids in that array.For example innerHTML was Football,Basketball, then that will be stored in an array and then ids Football Basketball will be extracted from it and then ids with the name football and basketball will have backgroundColor changed onpage load.Here cluster is the textarea name.

Here is the code:

```
window.onload = checkids;
window.onload = btnsInit;
var selected = {};//keeps list of selected links
var val="";

function checkids() {
var check=document.getElementById("cluster").value;
selected = check.split(',');
var j, i, a = document.getElementById('boxpopup').getElementsByTagName('a');
for(j=0;j < selected.length; j++) {
for(i=0;i < a.length ; ++i) {
    if(selected[j]==a[i]) {
        this.style.backgroundColor="#2BBBF3";
        }
    }
}
}
function checkids() {
var check=document.getElementById("cluster").innerHTML;
selected.push(check);
//extract ids from select and change their background color
}

function btnsInit() {
var i, a = document.getElementById('boxpopup').getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i].onclick = btnClick;
}
}

function btnClick(e) {
if (selected[this.id]) {
this.style.backgroundColor ="grey";
    delete selected[this.id];//deleting if already been clicked
} else {
this.style.backgroundColor ="#2BBBF3";
    selected[this.id] = this.id;//adding to the selected list
}
updateTextArea();

xPreventDefault(e);
return false;
}

function updateTextArea() {
var cluster = document.getElementById('cluster');
for ( var id in selected) {
    val += selected[id] + ",";
}
cluster.value = val;//updating from selected list
}

function xPreventDefault(e) {
if (e && e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
else if (window.event)
    window.event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: And what's the problem you're having; what do you want us to *help* with?

Comment: ca helpifyou create a http://jsfiddle.com replicating the issue...

Comment: As mentioned im creating a checkid function where it is doing things as told...but the array doesnt seem to change...also im not able to perform other things as said above

Comment: @david thomas anything?

Comment: okay guys i have added a function here named checkids.hope now u can see whats required and find the mistakes.thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right answer but....a textarea does not have innerHTML...it only has a value property...which is kinda obvious since textareas can only contain text...

**Edit:** Apparently it does have an `innerHTML`, but it is readonly and only holds the original textarea value. [See for yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/E5XJV/)

Comment: Im a newbie ...so i dont know...but what i can tell is im getting <textarea id="cluster">Football,Basketball,</textarea> from backend...now im performing clientside operations

Comment: OK, well avoid using `innerHTML`...it's going to give you the wrong value anyway.

Comment: Well since im getting those as innerhtml then what should i do?